# Difference between Oh and O

Tags: word-meaning

I heard that Oh and O don't mean the same thing, and O is used to add a syllable to a verse and doesn't have any meaning attached while Oh means that the person feels an emotion, sadness, regret, etc. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that the two spellings are often used in different ways.

The exclamation "Oh!" can express various things such as surprise, emotion ("Oh, how I hate this weather!"), or can be a way of attracting someone's attention ("Oh, John, before you go, can I just ask you...?").

The spelling *O* used to be used for the exclamation, but is now reserved for addressing someone in formal or poetic language.

> Give peace in our time, O Lord (Book of Common Prayer).

As you say, it is also sometimes used to add an extra syllable to a line in folk songs and the like.

Answer (score 0):

"O"
The English vocative particle O, an archaic form of address, e.g. Thou, O king, art a king of kings. However, lowercase o is also occasionally seen in this context.
[capital O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization)
Wikipedia

It is a way to directly address an important person or idea. Used in poetry and old English. Vocative in Latin was for direct address, so that is where it comes from, the Latin case called vocative.

Whereas: *Oh* is an interjection showing surprise.

Comment: Also used in the Canadian national anthem, "O Canada".

Comment: @CanadianYankee And in the American one: "O say can you see". National anthems are songs, which are poetry.

Comment: O tempora! O mores!